# How to get the updated argument(s) of a build process template refreshed in 'Process' section of a build definition?

Tags: arguments, build-definition, build-process-template

For a `build process template`, we can add/remove/edit the argument list of it and use it as variables within the build/work-flow steps. I reading the nice guide [here](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/27/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-2-Add-arguments-and-variables.aspx)

I'm cloning the template *DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml* to `sayHello-DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml` and edit it via Visual Studio 2012. I first added one argument, called `TestMessage`. I check in my changeset to the Source Control.

Then I create a build definition *sayHelloBuild* based on this template. And when I go to the `Process` tab, I can see `TestMessage` in the Misc section. I save the build definition. Trying to queue it and it gets succeeded.

Here comes the issue. I added another argument for the template named `ABBCCC` and checkin the source code. But when I edit the build definition  *sayHelloBuild*, I cannot see `ABBCCC` in the `Process` tab as `MyArugment01` does.

How can I get the argument list refreshed?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the below script to delete the registed build process template in Database:

   `use Tfs_YourTeamCollectionName;
   delete from tbl_BuildProcessTemplate where ProcessTemplateID = 'Your ProcessTemplateID';`
2. Create new build definition again.

The database name is your TFS team collection name e.g. Tfs_YourTeamCollection in the backend SQL Server of your TFS server. I'm using TFS 2012.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 7):

Within the arugments there is a property called "Metadata" as shown in the picture below. Click on the button at the right end and a window should pop up as shown in the second picture. Enter the name of the new variable in the Parameter Name and enter the other details (Display name etc). Save and check-in the build definition and you should be good to go.

[image: MetaData property]

[image: Add properties window]

Comment: I did put it into Metadata as you recommended but it seems to cache the previous data somewhere and not getting refreshed :-(

Comment: Are you sure you are making changes to the "sayHello-DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml" file?

Comment: For the Property can you check the Category field (In the above 2 picture you can see the "Category:" field)? Make sure that you have the "Category:MISC" for it to show up under MISC or else check for the property under the other categories

Comment: Also make sure you set the "view this parameter when" property to "Always show this paramter"

Comment: @Isaiah4110 This seems to be a bug. I'm having hard time dealing with this issue. Try to change the category value from "Build" to "#100 Build" and check?