# How to refresh build process template in Process section when creating new build definition via TFS 2012

Tags: refresh, build-definition, build-process-template

When creating a new build definition, we have the `Process` section as below snapshot where the items in the list is untouchable - i.e. I don't know how to refresh and/or clear that list and add new ones (by hitting `New` button next to it).

If you know how to, please share.

ps.
A google for this question comes up with [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2bb4cfef-f239-4841-8656-761f6ef41c3b/possible-bug-tfs-2012-build-process-template?forum=tfsbuild); and it seems the cache folder might relate to this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004379/how-to-get-the-updated-arguments-of-a-build-process-template-refreshed-in-pro/21035845#21035845) can be applied to this question.

1. Use the below script to delete the registed build process template in TFS database:

`use Tfs_YourTeamCollectionName;

delete from tbl_BuildProcessTemplate where ProcessTemplateID = 'Your ProcessTemplateID';`

2. Create/Edit new build definition again.

The database name is your TFS team collection name e.g. Tfs_YourTeamCollection in the backend SQL Server of your TFS server. 
I'm using TFS 2012.

Hope it helps!