# Can not remove unnecessary arguments of a build process template

Tags: tfs, build-definition, build-process-template

Currently, my build process template has some redundant arguments that I want to remove: 
[image]

I open this template in visual studio and remove the argument from the list:
[image]

Then, I check in modified template to TFS and refresh the build process template. But it seems nothing happen, redundant arguments is still there. I think it is because of some kind of cache. I try to restart visual studio and recreate build definition, but it not work.

I found a post say that we need to delete this build process template in tfs database: [here is it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004379/how-to-get-the-updated-arguments-of-a-build-process-template-refreshed-in-pro) . But I do not have permission to do this for now. Is there any other way I can do to clear the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your situation:

- First double check your template `xxx .xaml`  in TFS server to make
  sure this arguments has been deleted and check in the server.
- Try to delete TFS cache by going into default `C:\ {User Profile    Folder}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache` and VS  cache in appdata folder.
- Also try to delete the arguments in `metadata` Property as below. More detail from [MSDN](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/27/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-2-Add-arguments-and-variables.aspx):
  [image]

If it still doesn't work and you don't have the permission to TFS database. The final workaround, just create a new template with the same setting to your template  without this redundant arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I make it work by create a new template any apply it